# jcenter() is shutting down now, please tell me how can I use - "link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0" -this library?

Tags: java, android, jcenter

I am new in Android Studio. I want to use a library:

```
implementation 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'
```

But error comes up

> Failed to resolve: link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0

It need Jcenter(). But jcenter is shutting down. Then how can I use the library?

Comment: Does https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration answer this?

Comment: "But jcenter is shutting down" -- JCenter is pledging to stay open for legacy artifacts like this indefinitely. However, that library has not been updated in nearly six years, so you should be looking for some alternative library anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as a jitpick library.

To implement , follow the steps:

1. Add it to you `settings.gradle` file:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

2. Add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.github.flschweiger:SwipeStack:0.3.0'
```

It is very easy to use. This will now build.

Comment: Thanks a lot... now it's working fine.

Comment: You can upvote also @MKRoy